# Prolonged operation on blazor server

Tags: blazor

I upload a text file to the server. I then start an "X" function that reads the file line by line and saves the data to a database. What I want to do is display a progress indicator for function "X" to the client. Any idea how to achieve this? Maybe an example code?
The file is sent to an End Point and from there the "X" function is called. What I want to do is call another endpoint and get the progress of the operation. I really have no idea how to do it or the approach I should follow.
What is true is that the text file is sent to an End Point.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You use a timer.

```
@page "/"

Counter value is @(counter) : @(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))

@code
{
    int counter;
    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer((c) =>
            {
                counter++;
                StateHasChanged();
            }, null, 1000, 1000);
        }
        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```